# Detect shapes and create histograms

Tags: android, opencv, histogram, paint

I am working on an app that will compare histograms in hopes to match faces.
The app allows the user to take a photo, select a few key points in the image and then the app draws circles around those points. I then detect the circles using the OpenCV Hough Circle Transform functions. Up to this point the app works great.

What I need to implement now is one of two options:

1. Detect the circles and create separate histograms for the area inside of each circle.
2. Detect the circles and blackout the area(s) around the circles and create one histogram.

I'm leaning towards method 2, but I'm not sure how mask/color/paint around the area outside of the circles after they are detected. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of painting the area outside the circles in the original image, why not create a new image and copy the content of the circles to it?

Another point is that histograms are independent of translation. So, it does not matter if you copy the circles to the exact locations in the new image.

Do clarify if I did not answer your question, or if you have other questions now.

Comment: Thank you Totoro. You're second point is clear. I like your idea to just copy the important regions, I'm not quite sure how to implement that though. I know that I can cut/crop a bitmap using Canvas and Paint classes, but specifying the unique path(s) to cut seems a bit out of reach at the moment.

Comment: If the user selects the points, you can use a function to calculate all the points within a circle around that point at a certain radius. The algorithm goes as:
1. Take a square around the point, with the point at the centre and the circle diameter equal to the side of the square.
2. For each point in this square, calculate distance from the centre. Remove points that have distance larger than the circle radius, and copy the rest to a new image.

cv::Mat is a great class where you can do a lot of things. You will fond most of the functions you need right there.

Comment: Thank you Totoro. Due to time constraints I went with a simpler(although not as accurate) method. I am creating one large rectangle to enclose the area of the input touches and cutting that rectangle out with canvas,clipRect(). For now I think this is enough but I may refine it later for more accuracy. I appreciate your time thank you.

Comment: Right, a rectangle should do if there is not much rotation. You can add various methods and improve accuracy as you move on. Good luck!